# grep for IP without last octet as 0

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am trying to extract IPs from multiple web generated lists, and need to isolate the ones that **do not** end with 0.

Eg, in the list below, it has text, regular IPs and IP ranges. What I'm trying to do is to get only regular IPs and not anything that ends in a 0 or a subnet mask:

```
; Spamhaus DROP List 2016/07/03 - (c) 2016 The Spamhaus Project
; http://www.spamhaus.org/drop/drop.txt
; Last-Modified: Sun,  3 Jul 2016 21:18:32 GMT
; Expires: Sun, 03 Jul 2016 23:26:45 GMT

1.0.1.0/24
223.223.176.0
129.130.100.100
1.160.118.30
```

If I run `grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'`

it gives me:

```
1.0.1.0
223.223.176.0
129.130.100.100
1.160.118.30
```

I've tried to substitute the last part of the regex as:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[^1-255]'
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm trying to minimize the use of multiple piped greps (or sed/awk) to speed up the search process.  Eg what I'm hoping to avoid is to:

```
grep <all IPs from list> | grep -v <all those that end in 0 or subnet>
```

Is it possible to use grep/sed/awk in a single line to get me those IPs? In the above example, the result should be:

```
129.130.100.100
1.160.118.30
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not just use `grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.0'`?

Comment: @sato Seriously? Clarifying a question was the big dip?

Comment: @Dave you want to remove all other lines ? result should contain only those IP's ?

Comment: @Rahul ... yes. Only IPs, they shouldn't have 0 at the end.

Comment: You seem to have asked this question twice...

Answer (score 1):

You can try `awk`:

```
$ awk -F . '$NF !~ /^0/' <file
129.130.100.100
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. In the above example,  the only output should be 129.130.100.100. Anything ending with a 0 (whether it has a netmask or not) should be ignored.

Comment: @Dave Did you try it?

Comment: @Dubu I've opened a better formed question here:
(http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/293957/extracting-ips-from-a-web-list)

Comment: @Dave please don't do that. If this answer (or any of the others here) solves the question you asked about here, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer for original version of question

```
$ awk -F'[./]' '($4+0) != 0' iplist
129.130.100.100
```

#### How it works

- `-F'[./]'`

  This sets the field separator to either of `.` or `/`.  In this way the last octet will always be field 4.
- `($4+0) != 0`

  This logical condition evaluates to true if the fourth octet is *not* 0.  Since we included no explicit action for this condition, awk performs the default action which is to print the line.

  We add `0` to the fourth field just to be sure that awk is performing an numerical comparison, not a string comparison.

Comment: Can it be done with grep?

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E '^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$'
```

`[1-9]` checks that the first digit of the last octet is non-zero - the optional digits following it mean you can still match later zeroes (`129.130.100.100`).

`$` ensures that the line ends after the last octet, so it won't match anything with a subnet mask.

Your `[^1-255]` doesn't do what you want for a couple of reasons:

- It handles characters, not numbers: It means "(between `1` and `2`) OR `5` OR `5`"
- `^` means "*not* in this range"

So it excludes everything whose last octet starts with a 1, 2 or 5, and matches the rest.