# Extracting IPs from a web list

Tags: awk, sed, grep, ip

I am trying to extract IPs from a huge web generated list which contains a mix of text, IPv4 & IPv6 IPs, newlines, IP ranges etc.

Below is a snippet from the list:

```
; Spamhaus DROP List 2016/07/03 - (c) 2016 The Spamhaus Project
; http://www.spamhaus.org/drop/drop.txt
; Last-Modified: Sun,  3 Jul 2016 21:18:32 GMT
; Expires: Sun, 03 Jul 2016 23:26:45 GMT

1.0.1.0/24
223.223.176.0
129.130.100.100
1.160.118.30
91.121.120.228 # 2016-07-05, ns350944.ip-91-121-120.eu, FRA, 1                        
62.210.111.59 # 2016-07-05, sender9p2.offresduweb.fr, FRA, 1                            
52.90.253.169 # 2016-07-05, ec2-52-90-253-169.compute-1.amazonaws.com, USA, 13                  
2a01:4f8:200:2153::2 # 2016-06-27, 2a01:4f8:200:2153::2, DEU, 2                                
2601:1c1:8801:618c:9864:3f33:7569:38c4  # 2016-06-28, 2601:1c1:8801:618c:9864:3f33:7569:38c4, USA, 2
#last updated 2016.07.04 1733 UTC

1.0.1.0/24  China
1.0.2.0/23  China
1.0.8.0/21  China
1.0.32.0/19  China
1.1.0.0/24  China
```

For a bigger snippet, please see [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/p0rgf8P6) This is not the full list btw, as the actual one has over 44k lines.

What I'm trying to do is to get only regular IPs (IPv4) from the list.

Here is what I ran against the above:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}'
```

and it gives me:

```
1.0.1.0
223.223.176.0
129.130.100.100
1.160.118.3
198.55.103.144
etc
etc
```

Now, this is fine but I don't want anything that ends in '.0' ( eg 1.0.1.0 or 223.223.176.0) as they are IP ranges and not actual IPs. So I piped the output of the above grep to an awk statement which strips off all the IPs ending in 0.

The `grep (IPs) | awk (remove those that end in 0)` solution works, but I'd like to know if there is a better way to do it and minimize the use of multiple piped greps (or sed/awk).

Comment: Note that some hosts do have addresses that end in .0 .  What I think you don't want is the network blocks, i.e. the ones with a "/n" after them, they specify networks rather than hosts.  For example the entry 223.223.176.0 in that sample specifies a single host (which as it turns out, doesn't legitimately exist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the entire task with awk (assumes the pathname, of course):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*$/ {
        print;
        next;
}
/^[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\.[1-9][0-9]*[^0-9\.:].*$/ {
        sub("[^0-9.].*$","");
        print;
}
```

The first pattern matches just an IPv4 (no following text), and the second allows for some other text to match (and excludes the lines with colons).

By the way, the patterns should be anchored using **`"^"`** and **`"$"`** to skip unwanted matches.

This is shown as a script, which could then be run just like any other command (such as a pipe with grep):

```
./foo <foo.in
```

gives

```
129.130.100.100
1.160.118.30
91.121.120.228
62.210.111.59
52.90.253.169
```

I split the match into two expressions to simplify handling stray text after the IP-address.  That range `[^0-9:\.:]` ensures that there is at least one stray character to deal with.

An awk program need not be a script, but is free-format (and the line-breaks could be discarded when making a single command-string).  However, the result would be hard to read as a single-line.

Unlike the suggestions to use the `-o` option of `grep -E` or the `-E` option of `sed`, this `awk` solution should work on any POSIX system.

For reference (POSIX):

- [awk - pattern scanning and processing language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)
- [grep - search a file for a pattern](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)
- [sed - stream editor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

Comment: Your awk loses on the lines that have comments.  Probably just add `([\w]*#.*)?` before the $.

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you. I ran this against the pastebin list which I posted above and it runs fine. The only thing it did not pick up was 223.223.176.0

Comment: @MAP: The ones with comment came out fine, eg: 36.77.166.158 in the pastebin list. Not sure which one you are referring to? Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas: 223.223.176.0 appears to be network block and not an IP, as per the source web list: 223.223.176.0/20

Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you. On a set with 44K lines, it took just under a sec to process the list.

Comment: @Dave Oh, right, I misread the second RE (my brain probably still had the first one in cache and confused them).

Answer (score 1):

Just specify that you don't allow `0`s at the end in your regex:

```
$ grep -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[1-9][0-9]*' file 
129.130.100.100
1.160.118.30
91.121.120.228
62.210.111.59
52.90.253.169
```

The trick is the `\.[1-9][0-9]*`, which means match a `.`, then any number greater than 0 once (you can't have IPs ending in `019` or similar numbers) and then 0 or more numbers from 0 to 9.

I would also use `grep -E` to simplify the syntax:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[1-9][0-9]*' file
```

Or, even simpler:

```
grep -Eo '([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[1-9]\d*' file
```

And, if your `grep` supports it, `grep -P` to simplify further:

```
grep -Po '(\d{1,3}\.){3}[1-9]\d*' file
```

Comment: Thank you. Interesting to note that on a line which had this entry: `5.9.83.211   # 2016-07-03, static.211.83.9.5.clients.your-server.de, DEU, 11`   , it pulled both `5.9.83.211` **and** `211.83.9.5`

Comment: @Dave if the IPs will always be at the beginning of the line, you can use `grep -Po '^(\d{1,3}\.){3}[1-9]\d*' file` to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I'm trying to understand your regex at the end which omits 0s. `.[1-9][0-9]*` . So that means it will match 10-99*?

Comment: @Dave no, it will match one digit between 1 and 9 (`[1-9]`) then 0 or more digits between 0 and 9 `([0-9]*`), effectively matching 1 to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E -e 's/[[:space:];#\/].*//;
             /\.0$+|[0-9a-f]{1,4}:|^[[:space:]]*$/d' spamhaus.txt 
129.130.100.100
1.160.118.30
91.121.120.228
62.210.111.59
52.90.253.169
```

(newline and indentation added to improve readability)

- remove comments and everything from the first whitespace on a line (i.e. replace with the empty string)
- delete lines containing:

  - `.0` followed by a slash or end-of-line
  - 1-4 hex digits followed by a `:'
  - empty and whitespace-only lines
- print everything else.

Same algorithm in `perl`:

```
perl -lne 's/[[:space:];#\/].*//;
           next if (m/\.0$|[0-9a-f]{1,4}:|^\s*$/o);
           print'
```

---

Output of a timing test script that ran each method 10 times in a row, using the full files downloaded from their respective hosts:

```
$ ./timing.sh 
input file sizes:
24K drop.txt
72K base_90days.txt
120K    sinokoreacidr.txt
216K    total

input file line count:
   793 drop.txt
  4997 base_90days.txt
  5400 sinokoreacidr.txt
 11190 total

tdickey.awk: real 0m0.367s  user 0m0.305s   sys 0m0.027s
terdon.grep: real 0m0.550s  user 0m0.514s   sys 0m0.029s
cas.sed    : real 0m0.531s  user 0m0.484s   sys 0m0.035s
cas.perl   : real 0m0.379s  user 0m0.341s   sys 0m0.036s

output line counts:
  4990 out.cas.perl
  4990 out.cas.sed
  4990 out.tdickey.awk
  4990 out.terdon.grep

output differences (if any):
```

(BTW, the timing.sh test script found a bug in my original sed script.  some lines were being printed with the trailing /CIDR. fixed)

The all produced exactly the same output, which is good :)

I ran this multiple times, on an AMD Phenom II 1090T.  The `sed` and `grep` versions had relatively stable timings with almost no difference between runs, a ms or two at the most.

The `awk` and `perl` versions had slightly greater variation between runs - up to 20ms or so...almost always within a few ms of each other.  Sometimes `perl` was slightly faster, usually `awk` was slightly faster.  probably because my system runs lots of other stuff at the same time.

On this CPU, given the tiny amounts of time to run any of these versions, there's no significant difference between them.  On a slower CPU, the differences may be more significant.  I've included the timing script below so you can test on your own system:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export TIMEFORMAT=$'real %3lR\tuser %3lU\tsys %3lS'
files=(drop.txt base_90days.txt sinokoreacidr.txt)

function timetest() {
  # first arg is title string, remaining args are executed.

  # prime the cache
  cat "${files[@]}" > /dev/null

  title="$1" ; shift
  printf '%-11s' "$title" >&2

  # 10 runs for each
  time for i in {1..10} ; do
    "$@" "${files[@]}" > "out.$title"
  done
  # unique sort the output, but don't include sort in timings
  sort -u "out.$title" > "out.tmp" ; mv -f out.tmp "out.$title"
}

echo 'input file sizes:'
du -sch "${files[@]}"
echo
echo 'input file line count:'
wc -l "${files[@]}"
echo

rm -f out.*

timetest tdickey.awk ./tdickey.awk
timetest terdon.grep grep -h -o '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[1-9][0-9]*'
timetest cas.sed sed -E -e 's/[[:space:];#\/].*//; /\.0$|[0-9a-f]{1,4}:|^[[:space:]]*$/d'
timetest cas.perl perl -lne 's/[[:space:];#\/].*//; next if (m/\.0$|[0-9a-f]{1,4}:|^\s*$/o); print'

echo
echo "output line counts:"
wc -l out.* | grep -v total

# check if they all produce exactly the same output
echo
echo "output differences (if any):"
diff -u out.cas.sed out.cas.perl
diff -u out.cas.sed out.tdickey.awk
diff -u out.cas.sed out.terdon.grep
```

Comment: Thank you. This works well, but is slightly slower compared to the grep or awk solutions above.

Comment: BTW, what kind of system/CPU do you have that it takes just under a second to process 44KB?  all versions took ~ 30-60ms for an individual run against 216KB of files on my AMD 1090T.  effectively instantaneous.

Comment: I'm running the scripts on an Edgerouter. There is some additional sorting/filtering done after the initial extract as well, which is probably why is takes that time. And thank you for your detailed explanation and test script.

Comment: Ran this on the router:
`24.0K   drop.txt
72.0K   base_90days.txt
120.0K  sinokoreacidr.txt
216.0K  total

input file line count:
      792 drop.txt
     4984 base_90days.txt
     5401 sinokoreacidr.txt
    11177 total

tdickey.awkreal 0m1.345s        
terdon.grepreal 0m1.150s      
cas.sed    real 0m1.681s        
cas.perl   real 0m5.778s        
output line counts:
     4978 out.cas.perl
     4978 out.cas.sed
     4978 out.tdickey.awk
     4978 out.terdon.grep`

Comment: Highest time was the perl @ `5.778s` . Then the sed @ `1.681s` . Grep was the quickest @ `1.150s`. The Edgerouter has a MIPS processor btw.

Comment: perl is ridiculously slow on that machine.  probably startup overhead (perl is much larger than any of the others).  still, that's for 10 runs.  for a single run, it's ~0.1 sec vs ~ 0.6 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just add an appropriate pattern to your regular expression. Instead of `[0-9]\{1,3\}`, you want something like `[0-9]*[1-9]` at the end of your expression.